# Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group with the property that there exists $a \in G$ such that $x^3 = xax$, $\forall x \in G$. Prove $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group with the property that there exists $a \in G$ such that $x^3 = xax$, $\forall x \in G$. Prove that the given group is abelian.

Here is how I did it:
$$x^3 = xax, \, \forall x \in G$$
$$y^3 = yay, \, \forall y \in G$$

By multiplying with $x^{-1}$ in both sides of the first equality, we get $x^2 = ax = xa$. Analogous, we get $y^2 = ay = ya$.

So, $ax = xa$ and $ay = ya$ $\Rightarrow$ $xaay = yaax$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^2y^2 = y^2x^2$.

Now, $x^3y^3 = xaxyay$ $\Rightarrow$ $(xy)^2xy = x^2xyy^2$. But $(xy)^2 = (yx)^2$, so $y^2x^2xy = x^3y^3$. By multiplying in the right side with $y^{-1}$, we get $y^2x^3 = x^3y^2$. By rewriting this as $(yx)^2x = x(xy)^2$, and by doing the substitution $(xy)^2 = (yx)^2 = t \in G$, we get $tx = xt$. So, our group is abelian.

Is this a correct solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I get the conditions.  the element $a$ is meant to be the same for each $x\in G$?  But....if the group is abelian that would mean that $x^3=x^2a\implies x=a$  for all $x\in G$.  In particular, we'd get $a=e$ which would imply that the group was trivial.  Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct but an overkill.

The group seems to be a trivial one:-
$$x^3 = xax, \, \forall x \in G$$
$$x^3x^{-1} = xaxx^{-1}, \, \forall x \in G$$
$$x^2 = xa, \, \forall x \in G$$
$$x^{-1}x^2 = x^{-1}xa, \, \forall x \in G$$
$$x = a, \, \forall x \in G$$

Hence there is only one elemnt in the group, $a$ which must be the identity. The group is trivially albelian.

The question was too easy. Did you make a mistake somewhere?